# How to replace certain elements of table column with corresponding values of another array of different size in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, replace, vectorization

I have a **categorical** table variable alloptions.Exp (96399 rows) having such values as:

```
'Mar1 15'
'Mar1 15'
'Mar1 15'
'Mar1 15'
'Mar 15'
'Mar 15'
'Mar 15'
'Apr1 15'
'Apr2 15'
'Apr 15'
'Apr4 15'
'May1 15'
'May2 15'
'May 15'
'May4 15' ....
```

and I have a 119x2 Expiration_Table array having these values:

```
'Mar1 15'   '06-Mar-2015'
'Mar2 15'   '13-Mar-2015'
'Mar 15'    '20-Mar-2015'
'Mar5 15'   '31-Mar-2015'
'Apr1 15'   '02-Apr-2015'
'Apr2 15'   '10-Apr-2015'
'Apr 15'    '17-Apr-2015'
'Apr4 15'   '24-Apr-2015'
'May1 15'   '01-May-2015'
.....
```

What I need is to create another table variable alloptions.ExpDate having the corresponding values from Expiration_Table(:,2), that is from the second column.

Is there a nicer way to do it by not using loops?

Comment: I suspect that `ismember` will help you. but could you please change the sample data in your question to be actual MATLAB syntax that creates the categorical table in a way that one can just copy and paste it into MATLAB?

Comment: Are the underlying strings like that? If you're trying to compare the string 'Mar1 15' to '01-Mar-2015', it's not going to work. You'll first need to convert the strings to a common format, eg. use datenum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
[v, w] = ismember(alloptions, Expiration_Table(:,1));
result = Expiration_Table(w(v),2);
```

In your example, with

```
alloptions = {'Mar1 15'
              'Mar1 15'
              'Mar1 15'
              'Mar1 15'
              'Mar 15'
              'Mar 15'
              'Mar 15'
              'Apr1 15'
              'Apr2 15'
              'Apr 15'
              'Apr4 15'
              'May1 15'
              'May2 15'
              'May 15'
              'May4 15'};
Expiration_Table = {'Mar1 15'   '06-Mar-2015'
                    'Mar2 15'   '13-Mar-2015'
                    'Mar 15'    '20-Mar-2015'
                    'Mar5 15'   '31-Mar-2015'
                    'Apr1 15'   '02-Apr-2015'
                    'Apr2 15'   '10-Apr-2015'
                    'Apr 15'    '17-Apr-2015'
                    'Apr4 15'   '24-Apr-2015'
                    'May1 15'   '01-May-2015'}
```

the result is

```
result = 
    '06-Mar-2015'
    '06-Mar-2015'
    '06-Mar-2015'
    '06-Mar-2015'
    '20-Mar-2015'
    '20-Mar-2015'
    '20-Mar-2015'
    '02-Apr-2015'
    '10-Apr-2015'
    '17-Apr-2015'
    '24-Apr-2015'
    '01-May-2015'
```

This also works if `alloptions` is **categorical**, such as running `alloptions = nominal(alloptions);` after the above definition.

Note that

- If a value in `alloptions` matches several rows in `Expiration_Table` the **first one** is picked.
- Values of `alloptions` that don't have a matching row in `Expiration_Table` are **ignored**. If you prefer to set them to a **predefined value such** as an empty string, use the following modified code:

Modified code to set values not found to a predefined value:

```
[v, w] = ismember(alloptions, Expiration_Table(:,1));
result = repmat({''}, numel(alloptions), 1); %// initiallize to predefined value
result(v) = Expiration_Table(w(v),2);
```

which gives

```
result = 
    '06-Mar-2015'
    '06-Mar-2015'
    '06-Mar-2015'
    '06-Mar-2015'
    '20-Mar-2015'
    '20-Mar-2015'
    '20-Mar-2015'
    '02-Apr-2015'
    '10-Apr-2015'
    '17-Apr-2015'
    '24-Apr-2015'
    '01-May-2015'
    ''
    ''
    ''
```

Comment: Nice use of ismember, and I think it works.

I'll still give a plug for using outerjoin though :P This really feels like a classic SQL table join problem and using tables and SQLish syntax seems more transparent to me!

Comment: A tiny comment: my answer and Mendo's will have different behavior if the 1st column of the expiration_table has repeated elements.

Comment: @MatthewGunn I had no idea about `outerjoin`. I don't use `table` data type much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! In database language, you're asking for a table join. if your data is in "table" variable types in MATLAB, you can join two tables on a common variable. If you want all the rows in table1 to make into your new table, you want a left outer join. In R2015b the syntax is:

```
new_table = outerjoin(my_table, expiration_table,'Type','left');
```

I believe earlier versions of MATLAB may have different syntax. Several comments:

1. This code assumes my_table and expiration_table have a variable with the same name, and the variable with the common name is the variable you want to match on. If not, you can specify 'LeftKey' etc...
2. Be aware that if expiration_table has multiple rows with the same values in question, you'll get a row in your new table FOR EACH POSSIBLE PAIRING!
3. It also assumes the common variable in each table are comparable. If you have different strings/weird formatting, you may need to convert to something comparable like a datenum (eg. `x = datenum(char(date_categorical))`)

Example of outer join. Staring with two tables `t` and `t2`

```
 t.d                     t2.d        t2.n
 ___                     _____       ____
'jan'                    'feb'        2
'feb'                    'asdf'       0
'mar'                    'feb'        2.1
                         'mar'        3
```

`outerjoin(t, t2,'Type','left')` would return:

```
 d_t     d_t2      n 
_____    _____    ___
'feb'    'feb'      2
'feb'    'feb'    2.1
'jan'    ''       NaN
'mar'    'mar'      3
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There is not any nicer way to do so as names may not be unique. Consider the following text for the Expiration_Table for example:

```
'Mar1 15'   '06-Mar-2015'
'Mar1 15'   '13-Mar-2015'
'Mar 15'    '20-Mar-2015'
...
```

What should happen if we have repeated elements in the first column with different corresponding values in the second column.

Or What should program do if it can not find any equal name in the first column?

Comment: Thanks guys ) you are real matlab geeks ). The code from Luis really worked the most elegant way. I modified it a bit and corrected the alloptions to alloptions.Exp. What I really needed was to add a new variable to the table is that there was a predifined value for missing expirations. If Luis didn't do that, I wouldn't be able a add a new column, since there must be the same number of rows.